# Ajax error function wont have any effect , just the success part?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, submit

I am very new to Javascript .I am working on this view , so button submit should save data and if textboxes are empty , there is an error javascript section that should reply a bootstrap aler No Data . But in all cases , the No Data alert wont show up , just the Success Alert , even if the fields are empty in this form .I would appriciate every help.

```js
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {



        var data = $("#myForm").serialize();
        var newUrl = '@Url.Action("Index","AspNetUsers")';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/AspNetUsers/Index1",
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#your-modal').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                    $('#your-modal').slideUp(500);
                    window.location.href = newUrl;
             //   $('#your-modal').modal('toggle');
              //  $('#your-modal').show();

                //$('#your-modal .btn-default').click(function () {
                //    window.location.href = newUrl;
                });



                //    window.location.href = 'Url.Action("Index", "Pages")';
                    //window.location.href = "/{controller}/{action}" //in your case, /employee/empl

                 //   window.location = "//www.aspsnippets.com/";
        //        }
             //   alert("done");

            },
            error: function (response) {
          //      alert('No Data ');
                $('#your-modal2').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                    $('#your-modal2').slideUp(500);

                });



            }
        })
        })



    })
</script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

```css
 <style>
     
       #your-modal
    {
        text-align:center;
    }



    #your-modal2
    {
        text-align:center;
    }


        #x:hover {
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #6699ff;
            border-bottom-width: 2px;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .col-md-6.active:hover {
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(4,4,4,.4) !important;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
@model CMSFC.Models.AspNetUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = " ";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}




<div class="alert alert-success" id="your-modal" hidden="hidden" >
    <strong>DONE </strong>
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-warning" id="your-modal2" hidden="hidden" >
    <strong>No Data</strong>
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>



    

<form id="myForm">
    <div style="display:block">


        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



            <div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid  ;box-shadow: 5px  5px 5px #99ccff;  border-radius: 5px;margin-right:10px;float:left;width: 55%; height:40%;margin-left:-10%;">



                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <h3 style="text-align:center; border-radius:5px;margin:5px;padding:15px;color:black">Title</h3>
                    <hr />
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 " })


                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })


                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed)
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>





                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordHash, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordHash, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordHash, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecurityStamp, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecurityStamp, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityStamp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                </div>

            </div>








            <div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid  ;
    box-shadow: 5px  5px 5px  #99ccff;border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom:10%;float:right ;margin-right:-5%; width: 55%; height:1
    00%;margin-left:1%; position:relative;">




                <h3 style="text-align:center; border-radius:5px;margin:5px;padding:15px;color:black">Title</h3>

                <hr />


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>






















            <div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid  ;
    box-shadow: 5px  5px 5px  #99ccff;border-radius: 5px; margin-top:-20%;float:right ;margin-right:-5%; width: 55%; height:100%;margin-left:5%; position:relative;">

                <h3 style="text-align:center; border-radius:5px;margin:5px;padding:15px; color:black">Title</h3>
                <hr />


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "x", @class = "form-control" } })
                        &nbsp;
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="btn-toolbar" style="float:left;">
                <br />
                <input type="reset" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />



                <button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>

            </div>
















        }




    </div>

</form>
```

```
e  // GET: AspNetUsers/Create
    public ActionResult Index1()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: AspNetUsers/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index1([Bind(Include = "Id,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")] AspNetUser aspNetUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.AspNetUsers.Add(aspNetUser);
            db.SaveChanges();
           // return Json("User Details are updated");
               return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(aspNetUser);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your Asp script is responding with HTTP error, don't expect that the JS error callback will ever be called.

Most of the modern web framework have something to help you with client side validation (but never rely on it). Or you can try to write your own:

```
$('input').each(function(k, v) {
  var v_val = $(v).val()
  if (v_val == null || v_val == "") {
    alert("Fill required field" + $(v).attr("name"))
  }
});
```

Something like this...

Comment: I have a completely another view , with all the code i posted here , that works perfectly , but only this view dont work.

Comment: That is possible, but jQuery ajax error is event called only if an error occurred with the request. I might suggest reading about [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [jquery.ajax.events](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).
you can slightly modify the error callback like this:
`error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                  } else {
                      alert('Unexpected error.');
                  }
              }`

Answer (score -1):

```
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var message = string.Join(" | ", ModelState.Values
                .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
                .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message);
        }
```